# Calling multiple Javascript functions on page load

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

I have been trying to call 4 JS functions from the html body when the page loads.
Each of these functions are calling JSP servlet to fetch data from database and populate in the respective list boxes. I am working on the edit screen where I am trying to prepopulate the listbox.

I am trying out something like this:

```
      //call the JS to prepopulate the metadata
    function populateOnPageLoad(){
        populateA(); 
        populateB();
        populateC();
        populateD();
    }
```

I also tried calling all the 4 functions directly in body onload.
It seems that it  is able to call only populateD() and display the data in the listbox. I have tested each of these in the insert operation and the JSP servlets work fine. I even changed the order of these functions to check if it is calling just the last function, but it doesn't seem to be working that way.

What could be the issue here and possible solution for this?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you add more code..? like either of your methods `populateA()`, `populateB()`......

Comment: also, where are these functions placed? In an "onload" event handler?

Comment: And are you able to inspect the network activity to see if each ajax request is being sent out for each function?

Comment: Why are you doing ajax calls on page load?  In almost all cases you should be able to just populate that data right on the page initially instead of doing ajax calls.

Comment: Reimius, I am selecting a value from the dropdown , and I am doing AJAX call to populate the 4 listboxes in my insert operation.   But in my edit operation, I am preselecting the dropdown value, so there is no event to populate the listbox. I am trying to populate the data using same AJAX calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am passing the record id (which I am trying to edit) to populateOnPageLoad() when I am loading the page. When I do so, it populates the relevant data from the previous record into the respective list boxes

Answer (score 0):

You should look at `window.onload` as opposed to `document.body.onload`.
Additionally, rather than setting `window.onload` use `window.addEventListener('load',populateOnPageLoad,false);` or

```
window.addEventListener('load',populateA,false);
window.addEventListener('load',populateB,false);
window.addEventListener('load',populateC,false);
window.addEventListener('load',populateD,false);
```

And if you're using ajax, make sure you're not overwriting the `XMLHttpRequest` objects of previous calls (i.e. make sure they don't share scope/variable names)

Comment: Sshac, should i add window.addeventlistener() in the js function and just call it from page load?    I am using Ajax to populate list boxes. In insert operation,i am handling thru dropdown change event. But in edit operation,i will not have the event 1st time when dropdown lods,as it has the preselect value from insert.

Comment: I am able to resolve this issue myself, took quite sometime to figure out the solution though.                                               I am passing the record id (which I am trying to edit) to populateOnPageLoad() when I am loading the page. When I do so, it populates the relevant data from the previous record into the respective list boxes.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
function populateOnPageLoad(){
    setTimeOut(populateA(),500); 
    setTimeOut(populateB(),500);
    setTimeOut(populateC().500);
    setTimeOut(populateD(),500;
}
```